# Set traffic for Google App Engine using migrate option

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-app-engine-python

We are on App Engine Standard running Python 3. Always used the following command in App Engine to migrate traffic after tests are passed.

> gcloud app versions migrate $VERSION --service=“default”

Today around 11 am EET it stopped working. It waits for very long time and than exits with error. Permissions or anything else we can spot are changed.

After some investigation we found out that the following works:

> gcloud app services set-traffic default --splits $VERSION=1

But we are afraid it drops all current connections.

We also tried (same as above but with --migrate):

> gcloud app services set-traffic default --splits $VERSION=1 --migrate

But it didn't work in the same way as the original command we used.

Any ideas what may have caused this and is it safe to use the "set-traffic" command without --migrate option?

Comment: Looks like this was a temporary problem in GCP. Now resumed to normal without any changes.